# Refining a Query formula with two 'where' conditions

Tags: google-sheets, where-clause

I need to write a Query formula to pull through unique values from another sheet, excluding rows that contain certain keywords and also excluding any empty rows.

I've written this formula:

=UNIQUE(QUERY('Sheet Name'!A1:AZ,"Select A where A is not null and where not A contains 'STRING'",1))

Unfortunately this gives a VALUE error. It works with either of the 'where' clauses but not with both.

What am I missing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need to add the seconde 'Where', it just implies that you continue to add conditions into that statement:

```
=UNIQUE(QUERY('Sheet Name'!A1:AZ,"Select A where A is not null and not A contains 'STRING'",1))
```

Comment: PS: are you importing the 52 columns A to AZ just to bring column A? Possibly is part of the example, but if not consider changing it so it doesn't handle unnecessary data and calculation's time

Comment: And yes, good point about the extra columns- thanks again :)